# Leave one out cross validation manually

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a manual leave one out cross validation.

I have my code here and ironslag contains 53 values. However, my fitted model only contains 52 so I was wondering what I did wrong.

```
for(i in 1:53){

  validation<-ironslag[i,]
  training<-ironslag[-i,]
  model1<-lm(magnetic ~ chemical, data = training)

  fitted_value <- predict(model1, training)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some edits to your code that I think should help!

```
 #First initialize the output vector as an empty object outside the loop.
        fitted_value <- NULL
        for(i in 1:53){
        #you did this part right
          validation<-ironslag[i,]
          training<-ironslag[-i,]
          model1<-lm(magnetic ~ chemical, data = training)
        #when you fit the model, use the newdata argument to predict on a new row
        #also, fitted_value needs the index [i], so the each loop doesn't overwrite the previous
          fitted_value[i] <- predict(model1, newdata = validation)}
```